# Fine-tuned model not giving expected results

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, fine-tuning, chat-gpt-4

I'm new to fine-tune a model using GPT-3.5-turbo.

#### What I want to build

I want to build a tool that generates name ideas for an app based on a given context
(for example I provide "Fitness app" and in response I get list of good brand names for the app).

#### Why I want to fine-tune my own model and not just use chatGPT api ?

when it comes to brand names generation chatgpt don't give prefessional, high quality names, it gives you basic ones.
so I said maybee I can train it using the top names on the market to get inspiration on how should the names be.

#### what I did

I scraped top 30 top apps and got their names on multiple categories (fitness, video editors, etc....)
the training dataset looks similar to this:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a smart brand name generator. I will provide you with the name of my app and you will generate me new unique names that are not in your knowledge. Provide results in JSON => [{name: DATA, explanation: DATA},...]"},
    {"role": "user", "content": "photo editor app"},
    {"role": "assistant", "content": "[
      {"name": "Photoshop", "explanation": "photoshop is a combination of photo and shop and it means ...."},
      {"name": "Lightroom", "explanation": "explanation here ......"},
      {"name": "Pixlr", "explanation": "explanation here ......"},
      {"name": "Canva", "explanation": "explanation here ......"},
      {"name": "Pixart", "explanation": "explanation here ......"},
      etc...
    ]"}
  ]
}
```

#### Using the model (Input)

now I just used the model like this:

```
{
"messages": \[
{"role": "system", "content": "You are a smart brand name generator. I will provide you with the name of my app and you will generate me EXACTLY 50 new unique names that are not in your knowledge. Provide results in JSON =\> \[{name: DATA, explanation: DATA},...\]"},
{"role": "user", "content": "photo editor app"},
\]
}
```

#### Model response (Output)

```
[
  {"name": "Pixlr", "explanation": "explanation here ......"},
  {"name": "Canva", "explanation": "explanation here ......"},
  {"name": "Photify", "explanation": "explanation here ......"},
  {"name": "PhotoXPro", "explanation": "explanation here ......"},
  {"name": "Gimp", "explanation": "explanation here ......"},
  {"name": "Prisma", "explanation": "explanation here ......"},
  {"name": "Luminar", "explanation": "explanation here ......"},
  {"name": "PixelMator", "explanation": "explanation here ......"},
]
```

#### What's the problem ?

there is 2 problems! The first related to number of generated names, as you can see in my example I included "generate me EXACTLY 50 new unique names",
but the number of generated names is very random, sometimes it generates 5, sometimes 20, sometimes 60.

The 2nd problem is the generated names, they are names of actual apps that are already used, and I specifically include: "names that are not in your knowledge"
so that it won't give me names that are used by other apps and instead generate new ones from scratch inspired by the ones on the model.